# Correct Comma Usage with String of "or"

Tags: commas

Is this comma usage correct with the sentence? I placed them more to add a pause after each listed item, but if it is grammatically incorrect I'm not sure I want to use it.

"It wasn’t wandering down Locust Walk, or enjoying warm, buttery Insomnia cookies, or even realizing I could make daily visits to the Reading Terminal Market that persuaded me to choose the . . ."

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"It wasn’t wandering down Locust Walk or enjoying warm, buttery Insomnia cookies, or even realizing I could make daily visits to the Reading Terminal Market that persuaded me to choose the..."

Remove the first comma and all is well.